# strptime and timeformat in for loop

Tags: unix-timestamp, strptime, mktime

I'm quite new to Python. I'm trying to convert a string object into a UNIX timestamp using `strptime` and `mktime`.

When I run my script in Python Shell, I get no errors - so the Date/Time format `strptime` gets as an argument must be OK. But when I try to implement the code into my full code (into a for loop) I get an error:

> ValueError: time data 'Wed Mar 09 00:07:38 2016' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'.

This is quite weird, knowing that the format is OK.

This is the script I tested in Python Shell:

```
import time
import datetime
datetimestring = 'Wed Mar 09 00:07:38 2016'
timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(datetimestring, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))

print timestamp
```

This is the code that doesn't work in my larger full code:

```
for row in rows:
    report = str(getattr(row, 'answerTime'))
    print report
    timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(report, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'))
    print timestamp
```